# Reference cell in function in quotes in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to check the cells in column A against the value in H2 in order to decide whether to include a term in the sum. However, the H2 is not interpreted as a cell, but rather a string below. How to make `H2` refer to the cell?

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,"=H2",C:C,"=Albert")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the right formula is:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,H2,C:C,"Albert")
```

Comment: What if I wanted a function other than equality?

Comment: then use this `=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,">="&H2,C:C,"Albert")`

Comment: And if it's in the middle of an expression? Is there a general way to escape it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Could you please, edit the question or post another one for that? May be comments are not the best place to ask.

Comment: I meant if H2 is in the middle of a formula. Perhaps for example SUMIF(E:E, A:A, ">=H2+I2"). There are hacks for simple cases, but in general say I want to compare to some function of H2, SUMIF(E:E, A:A, ">=f(H2)") and I can't simply put H2 at the end as in ">="&H2.

Comment: `=SUMIFS(E:E, A:A, ">="&H2+I2)`